# Removing Background of SKView - Particle Emitter - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, particle-system

So I followed [this](http://www.mattknott.com/blog/2015/how-to-spice-up-your-ios-app-with-sprite-kit-particle-effects/) tutorial and created a small particle emitter for when the player achieves a goal (kinda like a celebration).

I'm using a single view application, just like the tutorial, but I can't seem to remove the background of the emitter... so I get a black square underneath the particles.

I changed the `View`/`SKView` in storyboard to clear colour, but it still appears to be black when the app is run...

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-particle_emitter/ManipulatingtheParticleEmitter/ManipulatingtheParticleEmitter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013297-CH2-SW4) say this:
`To create an emitter with no background color, set the opacity in the color picker to 0.`

Which I did here in the `Particle.sks` using the editor:

[image: Picker]

But when I run the app, it still displays a coloured box the size of the `View`...

How can I remove all background, so when the particles emit, it's just the particles?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your scene view,  you need to allow for transparency, so add `self.allowsTransparency = true;` if you have a custom class for your view, or in the view controller viewDidLoad:  add `view.allowsTransparency = true;`

edit:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BokehScene * scene = [BokehScene sceneWithSize:_particleBackground.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    self.view.allowTransparency = Yes;
    [_particleBackground presentScene:scene];
}
```

Comment: I can never seem to prompt the `.allowsTransparency'. If you look at the tutorial, I build my view in a subclass, then place it in my storyboard :(

Comment: in your view controller, look for the viewDidLoad method, and make it look like my answer

Answer (score 0):

To make your particle emitter's background colour transparent, you need to set SKView.allowsTransparency = true, and Particle emitter scene's background to .backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)
 Example:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = SKView()
    skView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, 200, 200)
    skView.allowsTransparency = true


    let scene = Emmiter() // this is your particle emitter class 
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)


    skView.presentScene(scene)

    view.addSubview(skView)

   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** Control + drag from the SKView in your storyboard to the View Controller to create an outlet skView. Then enable background transparency and set the background colour to clear.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var scene: Emitter!
  var size: CGSize! 

  @IBOutlet weak var skView: SKView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      size = self.skView.frame.size
      scene = Emitter(size: size)
      scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
      skView.allowsTransparency = true
      skView.presentScene(scene)
  }
}
```